# I run odoo 15 on vs-code but these errors appear what the solution for these?

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, odoo-15

The errors is:

( /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 /home/abdulrahman/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 37511 -- /home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo-bin --config=/home/a /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 /home/abdulrahman/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 37511 -- /home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo-bin --config=/home/abdulrahman/odoo/config/odoo15.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo-bin", line 5, in

```
import odoo
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/**init**.py", line 113, in

```
from . import modules
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/modules/**init**.py", line 8, in

```
from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in 
import odoo.tools as tools
File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/tools/**init**.py", line 8, in

```
from . import pdf
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/tools/pdf.py", line 18, in 
from odoo.tools.misc import file_open

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 35, in

```
import babel
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/babel/**init**.py", line 20, in

```
from babel.core import UnknownLocaleError, Locale, default_locale, \
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/babel/core.py", line 14, in

```
from babel import localedata
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/babel/localedata.py", line 17, in

```
from collections import MutableMapping
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/**init**.py)bdulrahman/odoo/config/odoo15.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo-bin", line 5, in

```
import odoo
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/**init**.py", line 113, in

```
from . import modules
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/modules/**init**.py", line 8, in

```
from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in

```
import odoo.tools as tools
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/tools/**init**.py", line 8, in

```
from . import pdf
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/tools/pdf.py", line 18, in

```
from odoo.tools.misc import file_open
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/odoo/odoo-15.0/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 35, in

```
import babel
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/babel/**init**.py", line 20, in

```
from babel.core import UnknownLocaleError, Locale, default_locale, \
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/babel/core.py", line 14, in

```
from babel import localedata
```

File "/home/abdulrahman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/babel/localedata.py", line 17, in

```
from collections import MutableMapping
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/**init**.py))

This is the errors i want the solutions for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure if it's the proper solution but I experienced some difficulty with my python version and when I downgraded the version (to py3.9) it worked. You can Try it too. Also I suggest to check your launch.json configurations and make sure that all the paths and names have been set correctly.

Comment: Here's a useful link to configure your odoo in vscode 
https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/configuring-odoo-with-visual-studio-code